# How should "What transformer should I buy?" questions be handled?

Tags: discussion

With LED lighting becoming more popular (especially outside the US), questions asking about purchasing strips and transformers pop up quite often.  First of all, are these questions on topic?  Second, do we have a good answer already on the site that explains how to match these components?

Most recent example (with misleading title).

- [How to install LED strip where before I had a fluorescent tube?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/44670/how-to-install-led-strip-where-before-i-had-a-fluorescent-tube)

Answer (score 2):

Since the OP to that question really wants product specific advice (referencing a specific ebay link), perhaps a new question should be created that's generic and not product specific. Then we can mark all other questions as dups.

Answer (score 0):

This carries us back to the good old days of real DIYers where the products we used consisted of fewer standardized components and more cobbled together parts.

Just asking us to be a buying service for parts is not something we want to do.  But providing  guidance as to the type and capacity of the necessary components, and how they go together sounds like something that we could help with.